# error: package com.getcapacitor.community.firebasecrashlytic does not exist

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crashlytics, capacitor

I have implemented Capacitor plugin for Firebase Crashlytics in my Ionic 5 app following [this](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-crashlytics) doc. I completed all the steps but getting the following error.

```
error: package com.getcapacitor.community.firebasecrashlytic does not exist
                                                ^
```

This error is coming when Android Studio is trying to build the project. The error is comming the the `MainActivity.java` class in line `import com.getcapacitor.community.firebasecrashlytic.FirebaseCrashlytics;`

Comment: Did you make sure to register the plugin? Did you install the libs as per the first step?

Comment: I have followed all steps in the doc for Android. Plugin install, changes in 2 build.gradle files and changes in MainActivity.Java class. Could yo please let me know what do you mean by register the plugin?

Comment: @TapasMukherjee Please help me for this to implement this functionality in the big Ionic Project and how to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short**

There is a typo in README. I managed to fix it by adding `s` in `firebasecrashlytic`.

Just change `import com.getcapacitor.community.firebasecrashlytic.FirebaseCrashlytics;` to `import com.getcapacitor.community.firebasecrashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics;`

---

**Some fun**

There was [an issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-crashlytics/issues/9) related to this "bug". The issue [was closed](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-crashlytics/commit/82ba9ee5b152d447d59887590b68ec0613c58f52) without fixing the cause.

There are already a few pull requests ([like this one](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-crashlytics/pull/16)) waiting for approval.

Comment: Thanks @Vitk. The Android Studio error is gone now.

Comment: 2 months later and this important 1 letter typo still hasn't been fixed... crazy. Thanks though, this solution worked for me too.